# Open URL in new window in swift

Tags: ios, swift, url

I am trying to open an url in safari using `UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)` but it opens in existing window of safari. Is there any way to open it in a new window ?

Comment: I doubt if you have any control over that. You just ask the system to open the URL and it decides how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately you cannot. Apple does not provide a way to specify how the url is opened.